# Can I detect if someone is using a browser addon to download videos from a website?

Tags: video, web, embedded-video

Is there any way to detect if someone is using a browser addon to download videos from my website?

Answer (score 3):

It depends upon the method that the plugin uses to do its downloading; in almost every case, the answer is no.

Three methods that might work with some of the less well-written plugins:

1. Look for abnormal browser headers.
   Unlikely to work as most plugins will use the inbuilt web request functions of their browser.
2. Implement [CSRF tokens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).
   E.g. http://myssite.com/video.php will only allow playback from a video if using the token (http://myssite.com/video-serve.php?id=x&csrf-token=12345) provided in the embedded page.

   This will work if a plugin attempted to directly download the file without going via the embed page. Lots of plugins will work around this though by using the csrf tokens ([DownTheMall!](http://www.downthemall.net/) for instance)
3. Look at the referrer header
   If no referrer header is provided, this would, again, indicate a direct download.

As I said, these methods will probably be unsuccessful in most cases, but if you are determined they might be worth a shot.